# How to apply single sign on (SSO) to ASP.NET MVC5 and Identity 2.0 (individual user account)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, identity

I want to apply SSO to ASP.NET MVC Project. I Use 3 projects in a solution that use same identity databases. And authentication method is 'Individual User Account'.

At now, If I log-in some site(project) then connect other site, I have to log-in one more time.

How can I fix it?